# File lens doesn't display any files until after opening it the first time

Tags: 11.10, lenses

I'm running the final, 64-bit version of 11.10 on my Sony Vaio and the files lens, when first clicked, does not display any files. Only after about five minutes when I check back after opening it the first time does it work. I do not have this problem on the 32-bit version of 11.10 on my netbook.

Any ideas what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional. The dash is not meant as a generic search engine. It's meant to be a place where you can quickly find the things you're interested in. The only way Ubuntu can learn what it is you are interested in, is by observing your actions. This is what it does. The engine that provides this feature is called Zeitgeist, in case you're interested in reading about it.

If you want to search for a specific file that you've never used, then the file manager (your home folder) is the right place to do it. I promise you'll learn to love it once you realize that there are no completely irrelevant search results. Ever. :)

Comment: But the thing is, on my 32-bit netbook the file lens works immediately, giving me access to recently accessed files as soon as I start it up. On my 64-bit install, which like my netbook was an upgrade from 11.04, that information is available only after I open a file, and only then after about 5 more minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Bug reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/921665